# Android OpenGL ES 2 - Blending seems to always be additive

Tags: android, opengl-es, alpha, blending

I can't seem to get my blending properly working in OpenGL ES 2 on Android. What I have are textures with alpha channels that I want to appear with the corresponding alpha. The blending appears as additive even when the top drawn object has alpha of 1.0. In my fragment shader I hard-coded a value of 1.0 for the alpha, and realized it seems to be using **color**, not **alpha** values.

For example, it looks like this : [image]

Instead of this : [image]

I am drawing in the correct order, in this example the blue should be fully opaque over top of the gray square. I have tried multiple blending modes (one,one), (alpha,alpha), etc., multiple draw orders, and using and not using depth test. I have tried random blend modes that yield incorrect results, so the blending is changing when I set it.

I believe the problem is that opengl is blending additive color. (Alpha, Alpha) makes sense to me, and when I explicitly set alpha to 1.0 in the shader, I would think I would get a square (the actual shape the texture is projected on) that has a blue circle on it. This not happening puzzles me, I guess I don't understand the sfactor and dfactor blending function enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using the Android Bitmap class to load your textures?

Using GLUtils.texImage2D() to load alpha textures from a Bitmap on Android is broken. This is a problem that Google really should document better. The problem is that the Bitmap class converts all images into pre-multiplied format, but that does not work with OpenGL ES unless the image is completely opaque.

This article gives more detail on this [click here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/porting-opengl-games-to-android-on-intel-atom-processors-part-1).

Comment: Thanks man! the problem seems to be that GLUtils.texImage2D() automatically uses premultiplied bitmaps (and for some reason Android doesn't include a fix?) as you said. A working solution for me was to copy code from post #3 here : [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/uqbDPmP4L8o)  and use 
  GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

Comment: WebGL has this same "problem", though in the case of WebGL this behavior is [clearly defined](http://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/#2.4) in the specification.